# Analytics Exclude referral

Tags: google-analytics

I have two subdomains www.example.com, client.example.com and admin section at different admin.com. Tracking code is set with _setDomainName = 'example.com'.

I want to exclude refferals from admin.com in traffic sources report. I setup this Filter

Type - Exclude
Filter Field - Refferal
Pattern - admin.com

But it doesn't work. I see referral from admin.com in traffic sources (I am aware that filter doesn't work retrospectively).

Comment: What match type are you using? Maybe try to use "regular expression" and change it to `admin\.com`

Comment: I finally solved this with adding another filter with Filter Field = Campaign Source